# Append data in one dimenssional list to a multidimensional list

Tags: java, collections

I have a list as follows:

```
List<String> responseList = new ArrayList<>();
 responseList.add("test1")
 responseList.add("test2")
 responseList.add("test3")
 responseList.add("test4")
```

I need to add the data in the above list to the below list in which 0 th row should have values test1 and test2 . 1 st row should have test3 and test4

```
List<List<String>> ActualEmployeeList  = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: O..K Do you have a Question that can be Answered? (Handy for a Q&A site.) Note it's usually appreciated if you can demonstrate what research has been done to solve the problem, a code attempt is shown, and a specific question on something that went wrong with the solution attempted or where you got stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a simple `for` loop:

```
List<List<String>> ActualEmployeeList = new ArrayList();
for (int i = 0; i < responseList.size()-1; i += 2) {
    ActualEmployeeList.add(responseList.subList(i, i+2));
}
```

Possible streams solution. Not sure this is optimal:

```
List<List<String>> ActualEmployeeList = IntStream.range(0, responseList.size()-1)
            .filter(x -> x % 2 == 0)
            .mapToObj(i -> responseList.subList(i, i+2))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this. The key to this is that you do not always need to do i++ in your for loop. Also, I think it would make sense to create the lists separately instead of just adding everything to response list.

```
        List<String> responseList = new ArrayList<>();
        responseList.add("test1");
        responseList.add("test2");
        responseList.add("test3");
        responseList.add("test4");

        List<List<String>> actualEmployeeList = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i = 0; i < responseList.size(); i+=2) {
            actualEmployeeList.add(responseList.subList(i, i+2));
        }
```